# Get CRM OptionSet data

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to get the OptionSet key=>values from my CRMOnline. I have access to the SOAP endpoint and am able to do all CRUD operations. Stuck a little bit on how to get the information from the option set SalesStageCode so I can display it in a drop down on an external Account create form.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should use RetrieveAttribute message. Recheck [this article](http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/08/retrieve-installed-language-packs-in_19.html)

Answer (score 0):

A C# version from [CRM 2011 Programatically Finding the Values of Picklists, Optionsets, Statecode, Statuscode and Boolean (Two Options).](http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/crm-2011-programatically-finding-the-values-of-picklists-optionsets-statecode-statuscode-and-boolean-two-options/)

```
static Dictionary<String, int> GetNumericValues(IOrganizationService service, String entity, String attribute)
{
    RetrieveAttributeRequest request = new RetrieveAttributeRequest
    {
        EntityLogicalName = entity,
        LogicalName = attribute,
        RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
    };

    RetrieveAttributeResponse response = (RetrieveAttributeResponse)service.Execute(request);

    switch (response.AttributeMetadata.AttributeType)
    {
        case AttributeTypeCode.Picklist:
        case AttributeTypeCode.State:
        case AttributeTypeCode.Status:
            return ((EnumAttributeMetadata)response.AttributeMetadata).OptionSet.Options
                .ToDictionary(key => key.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label, option => option.Value.Value);

        case AttributeTypeCode.Boolean:
            Dictionary<String, int> values = new Dictionary<String, int>();

            BooleanOptionSetMetadata metaData = ((BooleanAttributeMetadata)response.AttributeMetadata).OptionSet;

            values[metaData.TrueOption.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label] = metaData.TrueOption.Value.Value;
            values[metaData.FalseOption.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label] = metaData.FalseOption.Value.Value;

            return values;

        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}

OptionSetValue optionSetValue = new OptionSetValue(GetNumericValues(proxy, "new_test", "new_local")["One"]);
```